# Integral of non-linearly transformed variable

Tags: integration, statistics

I have a random variable $w$ which is the sum of two stochastic components:

$\log w = a + e$

Both $a$ and $e$ are distributed according to Normal cdfs $\Phi_{v_{a}}$ ($\Phi_{v_{e}}$) with means $-v_a/2$ ($-v_e/2$) and variances $v_a$ ($v_e$).

I know that
$$
\int_e  w(a,e)  \ d \Phi_{v_{e}} = exp(a)
$$

However, I now need to solve this integral:
$$
\int_e  w(a,e)^k  \ d \Phi_{v_{e}} = \ ?
$$
where $k$ is an arbitrary, positive constant.

How do I attack this problem? I tried using a moment generating function approach but failed. Is there some additional information I need to know about the relationship between $a$ and $e$?

Comment: What is $\Phi_{\nu_e}$? What integration range is implied by $E$? If you want to integrate $w(a,e)^k$ with $k$ some positive constant, why do you need to use $r$ and $\hat{\sigma}$? Preferably you would provide a minimal problem. What do you mean "solve" the integral. Do you mean you want the distribution of $w^k$?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I clarified the notation following your suggestions. With "solving the integral", I mean obtaining a closed form solution as for the case where w is not transformed. Does this help to understand my problem?

Comment: I observe $w(a,e) = \mathrm{e}^{a+e}$, so $w(a,e)^k = \mathrm{e}^{ka+ke} = w(ka,ke)$.